# SafeArgs does not generate any class

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use Safe Args with the NavigationComponent. I have followed a tutorial, but I have problems because any class is generated automatically, so I can't pass any arguments because Classes (obviously) are not recognized

These are my **Gradle** file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.4.1"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.frangela"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

}

dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.4.1"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.8.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0'
}
```

This is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.example.frangela.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:name="com.example.frangela.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:name="com.example.frangela.ui.slideshow.InserisciSpesaFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_slideshow"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_inserisci" >
        <argument
            android:name="descrizione"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="ammontare"
            app:argType="float" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_stipendio"
        android:name="com.example.frangela.ui.stipendio.InserisciStipendioFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_stipendio"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_stipendio" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_resoconto"
        android:name="com.example.frangela.ui.resocard.ResocardFragment"
        android:label="@string/Resoconto"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_resocard" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_resoconto_to_nav_slideshow"
            app:destination="@id/nav_slideshow" />

    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

After that I resync my project and rebuild, but nothing changes.
I tried to follow different tutorials and questions but none of them solved my problem. What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, did you try "Invalidate Caches and Restart" ? .

Comment: Okay, and please check your gradle.properties file where you need to have android.useAndroidX=true  as per the documentation.

Comment: Tried both of your advice, but no Class has been created :-(

Comment: I repopulate your code and it has generated those classes.

Answer (score 0):

After some days, I have found that the code has been generated, but in different folders, so that I cannot see them

Comment: can u please specify where it has been generated ?

Comment: C:\...\AndroidStudioProjects\MyAppName\app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes\com\example\MyAppName\ui\resocard . My advice is to use search function